# Resizing UIViews inside another UIView dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am looking to create a scale that adjusts with how the user interacts with the view -- zooming in/out. My view is fixed at top center of my view. I only want to adjust the width of this view such as widening the horizontal view as the user zooms in and vice versa. The view itself contains 4 additional `UIView` representing the left and right ticks, a center tick, and a horizontal view connecting everything essentially like this:

|------|------|

My scale view is the container which contains the other 4 views. I am curious if I should use Auto Layout so the views adjust based on the frame of the view containing these other views? Or is there another approach? Draw this out using CALayer and using transforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally probably go with autoresizingMasks, they tend to be pretty consistent for me, at least when assigned programmatically.  InterfaceBuilder has been another story.

```
topView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Basically, this means that the bottom margin (from bottom of top view to bottom of its parent view) is flexible and the width of topView is also flexible.  All other margins will be maintained.  So, left side of topView to left side of its parent view will always be the same regardless of the size of the parent view. Same with the right side, topView will stretch appropriately to maintain these margins because its been granted the right to have a flexible width.

There is probably other ways to do this, but hopefully this helps give you some idea.

Comment: Yes, I turned off Auto Layout in IB and am messing with the resizing masks, seems to be working as I intend.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem here is the "four UIViews".

Instead, make *one* UIView: a view that knows how to draw itself as the scale measurement display, sizing its own drawing based on actual numbers (how long it should be at 100%, how far we are zoomed in or out).

Then just redraw every time a zoom takes place (easy to detect through the scroll view delegate methods).

You may originally have used "four UIViews" because you don't know how to draw in real time. But it's essential for iOS programming, so go ahead and learn how to do that and you'll be much happier.

Comment: I was literally typing a comment asking for more info on drawing when your link loaded!

Comment: I could write the code for a self-drawing "scale" widget such as you have described, in about a minute and a half. That means it can't be very difficult! :) And do not be afraid of a view that has to redraw itself frequently; this kind of drawing on iOS is very very fast.